# What kind of bulb is this and are there LED equivalents?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I am wondering if I can replace this type of bulb in this type of light fixture with an LED equivalent, or if I need a new light fixture altogether.

Here is the fixture:
[image]

and the bulb
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I understand the desire to avoid having to buy a new fixture while gaining the benefits of a LED bulb.  However, you might look at LED fixtures vs. the cost of an LED bulb for your existing fixture.  You may find that there are better brightness and color temperature options if you consider a fixture replacement.

Comment: These halogens make great reading lamps, but the LEDs are horrible for reading in my experience. My whole house is now LEDs (CRI > 80), but the reading lamp is the sole exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks to be a bog-stock halogen bulb, and yes, there are LED versions.

Measure the length before shopping. You'll want it in millimeters, generally.

Bulb shape is **T3 or R7S** as best I can figure. A good reference for those I have not found, but those seem to get product results when combined with **LED Bulb**

Comment: Note that the LED versions are really really big (wide usually on one side).   I don't think it should be a big deal here but if the cover is tight to the bulb area and if the socket for the bulb is low there is a chance it won't fit.   Big box sells these.    I have had issues with these bulbs more than any other type when converting to LED.   For some reason putting them on a dimmer - I have tried 4-5 brands of the T3s - works... and then after a few weeks it turns it into a brick.   (LED rated dimmer)   Buy them at big box so you can take them back easier.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation on this, I ended up finding some T3 bulbs off amazon that did the trick: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07QVKSQ85?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2_dt_b_product_details
They weren't cheap, but I couldn't find any others with a decent enough rating. Glad they work!

Answer (score 10):

That is an R7S bulb. From wikipedia:

> An R7S is a double ended, recessed single contact (RSC) linear halogen lamp measuring either 118 mm or 78 mm. Some less common lengths are 189 mm, 254 mm and 331 mm. These lamps have a T3 shape on an RSC/R7S base. These can also be known as J type and T type lamps.

You'll also see them called T3 or J-Type halogen bulbs - though I'm pretty sure those definitions are supposed to refer to the lamp holder, not the bulb. Searching for some combination of "R7S", "T3" and/or "J type" should find suitable replacements.

They come in different lengths - most commmonly 78 and 118mm, so be sure to find the right size. They also come in different brightnesses - some of those halogen bulbs are 300W or more, used where you want extremely bright lights. Keep that in mind when finding LED replacements - some will be a lot dimmer than what you removed.

There are plenty of suitable LED replacements. Stores have all kinds of styles and brightnesses of them.

Comment: 118mm are usually 200-300w, and 78mm 100-150W round here.  I'd have to look online for LEDs to fit, and most are dimmer (no more than 50% of the equivalent power) and/or well as considerably fatter, possibly not fitting in that housing

Comment: It's maybe woth noting that, in my experience, these bright light often are combined with a dimmer to adjust the brightness, and that may not work with an LED.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the halogen in a lamp with an LED equiavlent (Home Depot has them, so they shouldn't be hard to find). As mentioned, the one I bought cannot be used with a dimmer, and the brightness is indeed lower, but the color is good and I have had no issues since.